# Want to pass a list of values in PHP (as in Perl), not reference to array

Tags: php, arrays, perl, mysqli, parameter-passing

I'm hitting my head against a wall because the way I'm used to doing things in Perl doesn't work in PHP. This is most likely something so basic I don't know how to properly ask the question. The crux: I'm used to sending an array in list context as the argument to a function in Perl, but in PHP I'm only passing a reference to the array.

I'm trying to make a basic SQL query in PHP using MySQLi, for example, `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE first_name = 'Bob' AND last_name = 'Smith' AND city = 'Akron'`. The trick is, my code doesn't know beforehand what terms will be in the query. The query is formed on the fly depending on what search terms the user wants to use. In Perl that's easy. In PHP I'm not sure what to do. Asked another way: how can I dynamically form and pass a list of values in PHP?

What I'm used to doing in Perl:

```
my %terms = (
    'first_name' => 'Bob',
    'last_name' => 'Smith',
    'city' => 'Akron'
);

my @keys = keys %terms;
my $where_string = join(' AND ', map("$_ = ?", @keys));
my @values = @terms{@keys};

my $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $where_string";
# Should give me 'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE first_name = ? AND last_name = ? AND city = ?'
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(@values);
```

What I'm trying to do in PHP that doesn't work:

```
foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {
    $keys[] = "$key = ?";
    $values[] = $value;
    $types .= (is_numeric($value) ? "i" : "s");
}
$where_string = implode(' AND ', $keys);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $where_string";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bind_param($types, $values);  # Only I need to pass @values,
                                    #   the list of the elements of the array,
                                    #   not a reference to the array
$result = $sth->execute();
```

It could be my brain is so Perl-addled that I've forgotten all common sense.

Comment: always wandered why mysqli needs types while DBD::mysql can live without them.

Comment: Me too. This whole ordeal leaves me wondering why I'm using PHP at all. (Answer: so I know how to.)

Comment: I hope you are aware that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and not as performant as possible. You can fix both by using placeholders and passing the variables to execute.

Answer (score 5):

What you probably want is [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
$args = array_merge( array( $types ), $refs_to_values );
call_user_func_array( array( $sth, 'bind_param' ), $args );
```

Yes, it's kind of ugly; sometimes the flexibility of Perl is an advantage.

Comment: perhaps subclassing mysqli to hide ugliness.

Comment: Thanks! That eventually got me there. It took a slight bit more tweaking, since mysqli_stmt::bind_param expects, very specifically, a value and then a series of references. This worked:

Comment: $args[] = $types;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
        $args[] = &$values[$i];
    }
    
    call_user_func_array(array($sth, 'bind_param'), $args);

Comment: @LonelyPilgrim: Nice to see you got it working! Ps. If you want to post code in comments, wrap it in backticks ( ` ).  It still won't look very good, but at least it's a little bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks. It's especially tricky posting code from an iPad! That will help next time.